# Configure ObjecMapper to require mapped keys but to not fail if unmapped are sent

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I'm using `Jackson`'s `ObjecMapper` to deserialize JSON data into a certain Java model. I do annotate the fields/members with `@JsonProperty` as well.

What I'm trying to achieve is to configure `ObjecMapper` in such way that the deserialization process doesn't fail if I receive a JSON with more keys than expected, but I need to fail if for some reason the mapped (JSON) keys in the Java model are different and/or missing.

For instance, this is the Java class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public final class CustomMessage {
  @JsonProperty("first")
  private String first;

  @JsonProperty("second")
  private Integer second;

  @JsonProperty("third")
  private Integer third;
}
```

The JSON data I can receive must have `first`, `second`, and `third`...but could have as well some other keys, which I'm discarding.

This is what I have so far:

```java
new ObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
  .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
  .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
```

But still doesn't work; it doesn't fail if any of the "required" JSON keys aren't sent — due to `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`.

> The application doesn't use `Spring` or any other similar framework.

Comment: Set `@JsonProperty(..., required = true, ...)`

Comment: The usual approach is to use Bean Validation to say that the relevant properties must be `NotNull`, `Min`, and so on.

Comment: Indeed, that's the other option I have left, but this type is auto-generated, so I'm trying to avoid mapping to another type just for this, although it would be more accurate to express this in such way. I was hoping to cut some corners with `ObjectMapper` :)

Answer (score 1):

Jackson has a `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES` which you could enable such that if any property is missing, it would fail during deserialization and throw a `JsonMappingException`. The javadoc ([ref](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES)) for it specifies

> public static final DeserializationFeature FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES
>
> Feature that determines what happens if one or more Creator properties (properties bound to parameters of Creator method (constructor or static factory method)) are missing value to bind to from content. If enabled, such missing values result in a JsonMappingException being thrown with information on the first one (by index) of missing properties. If disabled, and if property is NOT marked as required, missing Creator properties are filled with null values provided by deserializer for the type of parameter (usually null for Object types, and default value for primitives; but redefinable via custom deserializers).

So you could have your `ObjectMapper` creation as

```
new ObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
  .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
  .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES)
  .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
```

In case there only a few specific properties that are required and not all the properties, you could set the `required` parameter ([ref](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required())) of `@JsonProperty` to `true` on the required fields. For eg in your case if only the property `first` is required,

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public final class CustomMessage {
  @JsonProperty(value = "first", required = true)
  private String first;

  @JsonProperty("second")
  private Integer second;

  @JsonProperty("third")
  private Integer third;
}
```

Comment: I think this will only work if I modify the object, right? Currently it has the same behavior: assign `null` to the fields/members that aren't sent...but it doesn't actually fail the process — by throwing any exception(s) stating the deserialization failed, etc.

Comment: This would work if ObjectMapper gets the right constructor for deserialization. Not sure if you'd need some extra work as you're using Lombok too @x80486